# Counting number of Json documents with a where condition on MarkLogic staging DB

Tags: marklogic

I wanted to know if we can write an XQuery in MarkLogic to get count of JSON documents with a key as "source1"

The staging table has multiple collections with JSON documents with below structure:

```
{
    "source": "source1",
    "name": "John",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-23 10:23:55"
}
```

I'm trying to get the total number of documents with the source as "source1". i.e,

> Select count(*) from data-hub-staging where source='source1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a **JavaScript** module, you can use a [`cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery) in order to target the documents that have the `source` property with the value `source1`, and then use [`cts.estimate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.estimate) to get the count of docs:

```
cts.estimate(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("source", "source1"))
```

and the equivalent **XQuery** module:

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), cts:json-property-value-query("source", "source1")))
```